# MS SQL UPDATE-SET 'Case' different results to SELECT 'Case'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an update statement which is designed to manage "jobs".  I process one job first whilst the others wait in line until the first one is complete.  After which they will be sent to process (far faster as I can leverage calcs from the first run).

To quote my own comment:

```
-- Set job status to 2 for where there is saved results file    
-- Where there is no saved results file:                                
--  --Set job status to 2 for one instance of each unique param combination     
--  --Set job status to 8 for all others
```

PseudoCode:

```
UPDATE #Jobs 
SET [JobStatusId] = CASE
WHEN    ISNULL([PreCalculated].[FileCount], 0) > 0 THEN 2
WHEN    ISNULL([PreCalculated].[FileCount], 0) = 0 AND [GroupedOrder] = 1 THEN 2
ELSE    8 END   
FROM    #NewJobsGrouped [NewJobsGrouped]
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT  COUNT([Id]) [FileCount],                        
                    [ResultsFile].[ParamsId]
            FROM    #ResultsFile [ResultsFile]
            WHERE   [ResultsFile].[IsActive] = 1
            GROUP BY [ResultsFile].[ParamsId]
            ) [PreCalculated]
           ON [PreCalculated].[ParamsId] = [NewJobsGrouped].[ParamsId]
```

where #NewJobsGrouped looks like:

```
Job ID || GroupedOrder || ParamsId
1460       1                807
1461       2                807
1462       3                807
```

This does not work.  Every job is being set to status 2.  However:

```
SELECT  CASE
WHEN    ISNULL([PreCalculated].[FileCount], 0) > 0 THEN 2
WHEN    ISNULL([PreCalculated].[FileCount], 0) = 0 AND [GroupedOrder] = 1 THEN 2
ELSE    8 END   [JobStatusId]
etc
```

Works exactly as I am expecting.

Why would these two case statements give different results?  Is there something obvious I am missing?  I honestly can't explain what I'm seeing and whilst I can probably use another temp table to hold the output from the select and have a simpler update - but I'd like to understand what's going on?

Comment: Give the contents for `Precalculated` as well

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't have #Jobs in it. That means it will use the last value from the result set for every row. You need to have something in there so you know what rows to match on.

Comment: What does this yield:

`SELECT  COUNT([Id]) [FileCount],                        
                    [ResultsFile].[ParamsId]
            FROM    #ResultsFile [ResultsFile]
            WHERE   [ResultsFile].[IsActive] = 1
            GROUP BY [ResultsFile].[ParamsId]
`